# How to do I2C on Arduino with SDA and SCL pin already used

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c

i have a Arduino screwshield from sparkfun that I purchased: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9729 which I used to put between my arduino uno and my 2.8" TFT LCD touch shield so that I am able to use the unused pins. I have to make an I2C connection between 2 Arduino Unos which I understand will require the A4 and A5 pins however the TFT currently uses both pins. also, my tft screen is from here: https://www.sgbotic.com/index.php?dispatch=products.view&product_id=2756

The schematics of my tft are: http://www.sgbotic.com/products/datasheets/development/02756-schematic.jpg .

I am wondering if I can just use the A4 and A5 pins using the screw shield anyway since according to the schematics, the A4 pin is connected to the LCD_RST or is the pin necessary for displaying images taken from the SD card? 
If that isn't the way, how should I go about doing it, does anyone know?

Comment: Please add a link to this in your question: https://www.sgbotic.com/index.php?dispatch=products.view&product_id=2756 The memory of the arduino uno will be filled before you can do something useful with it. I suggest to use the arduino mega or use a nextion screen instead. This example confirms that the reset is connected to a4: https://github.com/SGBotic/LCD-GUI-Library/blob/066d3c71cd00760af6da987e81b904bd36dbe29c/examples/display_text/display_text.ino

Comment: Even better, the chipKIT Lenny (like a Leonardo but far more powerful) with 2 I2C buses, plenty of RAM, and a professional TFT library (DisplayCore).

Comment: @Jot i see! thank you so much for pointing out that the uno memory may be filled else i would be wasting a lot of time. i've added the link to my question!

Comment: @Majenko, as in chipKIT Majenko-Lenny?

Comment: @Jot As in I designed it, yes ;) The chipKIT™ name isn't mine though - that's Microchip's property - I just license it from them.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't just use it. While I2C itself *may* work, the screen will keep resetting itself all the time and will be useless.

You may be able to get some luck with a [software bit-banged I2C](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/SoftwareI2CLibrary)  on other pins. However I would personally choose to modify the TFT screen's PCB and cut the LCD_RST signal from the A4 pin and connect a 10kΩ resistor to +5V, or re-route it to another pin. That way you can then use I2C.

Comment: Second the [Software I2C library](https://github.com/felias-fogg/SoftI2CMaster) (kudos felias-fogg, excellent work!). I have worked a lot with it and it performed really well. Had lots of trouble with the hardware `Wire` lib that went away with the software lib. Pick your own pins.

Comment: i see! thank you so much. as mentioned by @jot im afraid my uno will run out of memory so i will be switching over to the mega instead to save myself the trouble. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If the LCD is using A4/A5 for something besides I2C, than no you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

As I have very little knowledge about Prototype connection.But to avoid the soldering problems,

You May use [I2C adapters](https://store.ncd.io/product/i2c-shield-for-arduino-uno/) as well as [I2C cable joiners](https://store.ncd.io/product/i2c-extension-cable-adapter-i2c-cable-joiner/) will be much useful and are specially designed for expansion of more than 1 I2C modules at the same time.

Hope These Sheilds and Adapters will be helpful for you.